# How would I modify Zurb Foundation's in-line list to fix the list to a single row, allowing overflow: scroll?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm using an inline-list as described by [Foundation's documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/inline_lists.html) to display a list of images.

This works fine, but if the list of images exceeds the width of the containing element I want them to remain in one row and the have the overflow scrollable: `overflow: scroll`.

There seems to be an issue with the `li`'s (containing the images in my case) and the display: block style that they default to.

How would I change my list from this:

[image: inline list starting a new row]

. . . to a list of items in a single row that I can scroll horizontally to view images that overflow off of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by

- Setting the parent element's style to `overflow:scroll;`
- Setting the `ul` element's style to `display: inline-flex`
- Then giving the `li`s a minimum width, in my case `min-width:200px;`

My exact code (using haml in a rails app):

```
%div{ id: 'type-of-position', style:'width:100%; overflow:scroll;' }
  %ul{ class: 'inline-list', style:'display: inline-flex' }
    - @employer_types.each do |tt|
      %li{ class: 'inactive', style:'min-width:200px;', id: tt.id }=image_tag tt.image.url
```

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but it worked to accomplish what I was trying to do.

Comment: Flex-box is cool. And likely a good solution. But it is new (http://caniuse.com/flexbox) i don't know which browsers you need to support

Answer (score 0):

The `inline-list` is not suitable for your usecase. `inline-list` adds a `float:left` to all items and let them be. That in general is what you need. But `float:left` will break when the end of the parent item is reached. 
You need the element to stop from breaking. That can be archived by providing a wider parent item.

Update a much better solution the one before:
http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/RRd2L/1/

Append CSS like this:

```
.inline-list.real-inline
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
}

.inline-list.real-inline  > li
{
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And then add the class "real-inline" to the desired list. A bit hacky but it works... You sure find a better name.

-- previous solution (works but not that nice):
I'd suggest you add a new class like this one:

```
.horizontal-scroll-pane
{
    overflow: auto;
}

.horizontal-scroll-pane ul.inline-list
{
    /* This need to be wide. */
    min-width: 2000px;
}
```

Having this html:

```
<div class="horizontal-scroll-pane">
<ul class="inline-list">
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/RRd2L/